# Reset Radio input si se llego a marcar

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de setear mis campos de un formulario y me sale el siguiente error

mi codigo:

```
$('#limpiar').on("click", function(e) {
// document.getElementById('tipo_operacion').val = "";

document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=documento]:checked').checked = false;
document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=serv_locacion]:checked').checked = false;
document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=docn_siafumento]:checked').checked = false;
document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=v]:checked').checked = false;
});
```

El error es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podria realizar el limpiar los campos si no marco algunos inputs

Comment: Lo que quieres es que con un check "limpiar" desmarque a los demás?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entendí quieres desmarcar los **input radio** seleccionados y se puede hacer de manera mas dinámica con **querySelectorAll**.

```js
//ACCEDEMOS AL INPUT CON CLASE CLEAN Y ESCUCHAMOS EL EVENTO CLICK
document.getElementById("clean").addEventListener('change', function(){
//VERIFICAMOS QUE EL ELEMENTO ESTE CHECKED (CLEAN)
if(this.checked) {
  //OBTENEMOS TODOS LOS INPUT RADIO Y LOS GUARDAMOS EN UNA VARIABLE
  var options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');
  //RECORREMOS LOS ELEMENTOS
  options.forEach(function(element){
        element.checked = false; 
   })
} 
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="clean">Limpiar</input><br><br>
<input type="radio" class="option">radio 1</input> 
<input type="radio" class="option">radio 2</input> 
<input type="radio" class="option">radio 3</input> 
<input type="radio" class="option">radio 4</input>
```

Dime si es lo que buscabas.

Comment: +1, pero ojo, la idea es que eso suceda solo al marcar el checkbox y no cuando le quitamos el check, fíjate que cuando el checkbox está marcado, seleccionamos los buttons y desenmarcamos el checkbox, los radio buttons igual se desenmarcan, y debería ocurrir solo al marcar el checkbox. Creo que esto lo solucionarías cambiando el listener `click` por `change`.

Comment: Cierto, la verdad no lo aplique ya que no menciona si al desmarcar el check quiere que se marquen todos o que acción quiere realizar, esperaba a que viera la respuesta y diera mas contexto, quedo al pendiente para modificarla, gracias @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Perdón, veo que sigue sin funcionar :s, dentro de tu listener (justo debajo de `var options...`) pon `if (this.checked) {...}` y dentro de las llaves pon todo tu `foreach`, ahí ya creo que sí jeje... con eso validas que el checkbox esté seleccionado :-)

Comment: Listo, cambio la lógica.

Answer (score 0):

Puedo notar que usas `jQuery`.

Una solución simple es agregar una clase en común para los `input` que quieras desmarcar al hacer click en el botón con id **limpiar**.

Luego con `jQuery`, en el evento `click` del botón, seteas la propiedad `checked` a `false`... y eso es todo.

```js
$('#limpiar').on('click', function() {
  $('.radio-button').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="limpiar">Limpiar radio buttons</button>
<input type="radio" name="documento" class="radio-button" />
<input type="radio" name="serv_locacion" class="radio-button" />
<input type="radio" name="docn_siafumento" class="radio-button" />
<input type="radio" name="v" class="radio-button" />
```